# NodeJs: How do I fix package vulnerabilities dependent on another npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, npm-vulnerabilities

How do I sort out npm vulnerabilities dependent on another package.
For example I am getting the below error where the package **undici**  is dependent on the **prismix** package.

**Thinks I have tried:**

1. Running npm audit fix
2. Prismix is already updated to the latest version

> ```
> Moderate        undici before v5.8.0 vulnerable to CRLF injection in request headers                                                    
> Package         undici                                                        
> Patched in      >=5.8.0
> Dependency of   prismix
> Path            prismix > @prisma/sdk > @prisma/engine-core > undici
> More info       https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3cvr-822r-rqcc
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The authors of prismix may not have updated their dependencies yet.

You might need to wait for their dependencies to be updated, or you could try installing the version 5.8.0 of undici nonetheless and cross your finger that they are compatible.

To specify a version:

```
npm install undici@5.8.0
```